# Running remote command in background using paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, command-line, paramiko

When I tried to run the remote command in the background by using paramiko, I'm not able to see any output of the executed command in stdout. Please go through the below illustration.

**Script which runs the remote command normally:**

```
import paramiko
import select
import time
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('host_name', username='user_name', password='password')
COMMAND = "ls && sleep 15 && ls " #note here
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(COMMAND, get_pty=True)

while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
        time.sleep(1)
        if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
            rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
            if len(rl) > 0:
                print("{}".format(stdout.channel.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")))
else:
    print("{}".format(stdout.channel.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")))
```

**Output:**

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
<waits for 15 seconds>
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

**Same script which runs the remote command in the background:**

```
import paramiko
import select
import time
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('host_name', username='user_name', password='password')
COMMAND = "ls && sleep 15 && ls &" # here is the change
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(COMMAND, get_pty=True)

while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
        time.sleep(1)
        if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
            rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
            if len(rl) > 0:
                print("{}".format(stdout.channel.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")))
else:
    print("{}".format(stdout.channel.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")))
```

**Output:**

As you can see, there is a blank line printed on the console, and the program exits within one/two second(s). I doubt whether it actually executes `sleep 15` in the background and exits after initiates it or not.

Is there anything that I need to do in case of running the remote command in the background?

I'm new to the paramiko module. Maybe you can find this question simple. Please do share your comments. It'll be a great help to beginners like me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, apart from one comment in line begginning with `COMMAND` these 2 scripts are identical.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the ```&``` at the end of the ```COMMAND``` in the second scenario. Added now. Thanks, for pointing it out.

Comment: I have to run it in the background as part of my application's requirement and you can see, I'm waiting for its completion. For your second question, Yes, it is ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute a command in the background, the session ends immediately, not waiting for the command to complete.

Try this command:

```
ssh -t user_name@host_name "ls && sleep 15 && ls &"
```

It's an equivalent of your Python code. And you will see that it produces no output either. It won't even wait the 15 seconds, it closes immediately. Same as your Python code.

```
$ ssh -t user_name@host_name "ls && sleep 15 && ls &"
Connection to host_name closed.
$
```

---

*Anyway, I do not see a point of executing a command in the background, if you then wait for the command to finish.*

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I understand that we can execute and wait for its completion. But I do initiate a ```Command A``` in the background and start doing other actions in that same ssh session which can be done after executing that ```Command A```. Note: ```Command A``` takes much time.

Comment: So run A and B using two `exec_command` calls over the same SSH connection. That's the way to do it using a code. – Running a command in a background is an interactive shell feature for interactive human use. Not for code. – And your code is not doing what you want anyway. You wait for A to complete. You never execute the B (while A is running).